# python glob issues with directory with [] in name

Tags: python, glob

I am using glob to find all *.shp files within a directory, but the directory name contains '[]' and that is causing glob to fail. Any workarounds for this?

My code is:

```
glob.glob(sub_dir+os.sep+'soilmu_a_*.shp')
```

where sub_dir is:

```
'C:\\Users\\oh\\wss_SSA_OH001_soildb_OH_2003_[2013-12-19]\\spatial\\'
```

The error message I get is:

```
*** error: bad character range
```

Comment: note: you can use `/` as path separator. Python will translate it for you as appropriate for your platform (easier to read paths that way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the manual page, you can modify your pattern and wrap the offending meta characters. Change `[` to `[[]` and `]` to `[]]` (single character ranges corresponding to the meta character).

For instance:

```
pattern = sub_dir + os.se p +'soilmu_a_*.shp'
pattern = pattern.replace('[','[[]').replace(']','[]]')
glob.glob(pattern)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not return a file match even though one does exists at that path. Could it be that by doing the pattern replacement, we construct a path that no longer exists?

Comment: well `[[]` is simply a range expression containing only `[` so matches only the `[` character. same applies to `[]]` with the `]` character... so no.

Comment: one thing to note: your `sub_dir` already contains a trailing path separator and you're appending another. perhaps that's the problem...

Comment: Your double .replace won't work. Here is what will work: .translate({ord('['):'[[]', ord(']'):'[]]'})

Comment: double translation is likely to fail.

Comment: @EliaIliashenko Why would the double replace fail? I tried it out on an ordinary string on the python terminal and it works absolutely fine.

Comment: @Mugen because the second replace will replace „]“ symbols which appeared as a result of 1st replace.

Comment: @EliaIliashenko Beautiful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@isedev is right about the character range but double replacement is NOT a sensible thing to do.

```
import re
ptn = re.sub('([\[\]])','[\\1]',ptn)
```

`str.translate()` should also work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, glob failed to find subdirectories when the parent directory path had [] in it, and I got NO error message!  I found the problem by chance.  I could wish that I had gotten an error message.

I switched to os.listdir to get the subdirectories, and since I needed the full path to the subdirectories, I had to paste that back in:

```
subdirs = [d for d in os.listdir(current_full_path) if os.path.isdir(current_full_path + '/' + d)]
for subdir in subdirs:
    subdir_full_path = current_full_path + '/' + subdir
```

Answer (score 0):

From Python 3.4 version you can use glob.escape(path) that automatically escapes all special characters ('?', '*' and '[') in literal string so in your case:

```
glob.glob(glob.escape(sub_dir) + os.sep + 'soilmu_a_*.shp')
```

or

```
sub_dir = glob.escape(subdir)
glob.glob(sub_dir + os.sep + 'soilmu_a_*.shp')
```