# How to process files from one subfolder to another in each directory using Python?

Tags: python, windows, directory-structure

I have a basic file/folder structure on the Desktop where the "Test" folder contains "Folder 1", which in turn contains 2 subfolders:

- An "Original files" subfolder which contains shapefiles (.shp).
- A "Processed files" subfolder which is empty.

I am attempting to write a script which looks into each parent folder (*Folder 1*, *Folder 2* etc) and if it finds an *Original Files* subfolder, it will run a function and output the results into the *Processed files* subfolder.

I made a simple diagram to showcase this where if *Folder 1* contains the relevant subfolders then the function will run; if *Folder 2* does **not** contain the subfolders then it's simply ignored:

[image: Folder structure]

I looked into the following posts but having some trouble:

- [python glob issues with directory with [] in name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055500/python-glob-issues-with-directory-with-in-name)
- [Getting a list of all subdirectories in the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory)
- [How to list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python?lq=1)

The following is the script which seems to run happily, annoying thing is that it doesn't produce an error so this real noob can't see where the problem is:

```
import os, sys

from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

for subFolders, files in os.walk(home + "\Test\\" + "\*Original\\"):
 if filename.endswith('.shp'):

    output = home + "\Test\\" + "\*Processed\\" + filename

    # do_some_function, output
```

Comment: why not using "python -m pdb yourscript.py" to see if it did what you want or not? Eclipse/PyDev will let you have a nicer GUI debugging experience.

Comment: @DynoHongjunFu - Awesome, many thanks for this. I think _anything_ would give me a nicer debugging experience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mixed something up in your `os.walk()`-loop.

I just created a simple structure as shown in your question and used this code to get what you're looking for:

```
root_dir = '/path/to/your/test_dir'
original_dir = 'Original files'
processed_dir = 'Processed files'

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    if original_dir in path:
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('shp'):
                print('original dir: \t' + path)
                print('original file: \t' + path + os.path.sep + file)
                print('processed dir: \t' + os.path.sep.join(path.split(os.path.sep)[:-1]) + os.path.sep + processed_dir)
                print('processed file: ' + os.path.sep.join(path.split(os.path.sep)[:-1]) + os.path.sep + processed_dir + os.path.sep + file)
                print('')
```

I'd suggest to only use wildcards in a directory-crawling script if you are REALLY sure what your directory tree looks like. I'd rather use the full names of the folders to search for, as in my script.

#### Update: Paths

Whenever you use paths, take care of your path separators - the slashes.

On windows systems, the backslash is used for that:

```
C:\any\path\you\name
```

Most other systems use a normal, forward slash:

```
/the/path/you/want
```

In python, a forward slash could be used directly, without any problem:

```
path_var = '/the/path/you/want'
```

...as opposed to backslashes. A backslash is a special character in python strings. For example, it's used for the newline-command: `\n`

To clarify that you don't want to use it as a special character, but as a backslash itself, you either have to "escape" it, using another backslash: `'\\'`. That makes a windows path look like this:

```
path_var = 'C:\\any\\path\\you\\name'
```

...or you could mark the string as a "raw" string (or "literal string") with a proceeding `r`. Note that by doing that, you can't use special characters in that string anymore.

```
path_var = r'C:\any\path\you\name'
```

In your comment, you used the example `root_dir = home + "\Test\\"`. The backslash in this string is used as a special character there, so python tries to make sense out of the backslash and the following character: `\T`. I'm not sure if that has any meaning in python, but `\t` would be converted to a tab-stop. Either way - that will not resolve to the path you want to use.

I'm wondering why your other example works. In `"C:\Users\me\Test\\"`, the `\U` and `\m` should lead to similar errors. And you also mixed single and double backslashes.

**That said...**

When you take care of your OS path separators and trying around with new paths now, also note that python does a lot of path-concerning things for you. For example, if your script reads a directory, as `os.walk()` does, on my windows system the separators are already processed as double backslashes. There's no need for me to check that - it's usually just hardcoded strings, where you'll have to take care.

And finally: The [Python os.path module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) provides a lot of methods to handle paths, seperators and so on. For example, `os.path.sep` (and `os.sep`, too) wil be converted in the correct seperator for the system python is running on. You can also build paths using `os.path.join()`.

#### And finally: The home-directory

You use `expanduser("~")` to get the home-path of the current user. That should work fine, but if you're using an old python version, there could be a bug - see: [expanduser("~") on Windows looks for HOME first](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2007-July/039006.html)

So check if that home-path is resolved correct, and then build your paths using the power of the `os`-module :-)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks buddy, I will test this out and report back!

Comment: Awesome, tested your script and works great! Although I did have an issue when using `root_dir = home + "\Test\\"`. Nothing printed. But seems to work when I used the direct path ("C:\Users\me\Test\\"). Any idea as to why? Other than that, fantastic and I will take your wildcard advice into account!

Comment: @Joseph: I'm updating my answer and provide some informations about path names. Glad i could help :-)

Comment: This is a brilliant updated answer! Many thanks for this as it really clears up the PATH issues. I will play around with the different methods. Hope your answer gets loads of upvotes!