# how to look through the file in certain folder?

Tags: python, file

Let say I have a folder

```
/home/me/data/picture/
```

and picture folder include various of picture files. 
if I want to look through  all the file inside and get each file name.

```
while file in fileexist:
   y,sr = somefunction.load("/home/me/data/picture"+file.name);
```

is it possible how many files in certain folder? and get each  file names?

Comment: `os.listdir("some_path")` gives you a list of files in a folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to process files from one subfolder to another in each directory using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283466/how-to-process-files-from-one-subfolder-to-another-in-each-directory-using-pytho)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can use:

```
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    print(os.path.join(folder, file))
```

or you can use `os.walk` to iterate over all the paths within a given directory:

```
folder='/home/me/data/picture'
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(path, file))
```

or you can use a glob.

Comment: How to get only file name?

Comment: instead of `os.path.join(path, file)` use `file`

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

files_list = [f for f in listdir('your_path/to_folder') if isfile(join('your_path/to_folder', f))]

print(files_list)
```

result is a list, which contains all files in a certain folder

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [15.1. os — Miscellaneous operating system interfaces](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) and [10.1. os.path — Common pathname manipulations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

In your case, you can use os.listdir(path), which returns a list of all your files in given folder.

```
import os

path = "C:/home/me/data/picture" # full path to folder

# You can print the number of the file in the folder with
# the functions len() and os.listdir()
print(len(os.listdir(path)))

# You can get the list of the files in the folder with:
print(os.listdir(path))

# if you want a more readable outcome, print each file with for loop:
for file in os.listdir(path):
print(file)
```

for more operations, you may want to look to this functions:

[os.environ(path)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ), for the pathname of your home directory.

[os.chdir(path)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir), for changing directory

[os.getcwd()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd), for your current directory

[os.join(path, *paths)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join), join paths

and many others like mkdir, makedirs, remove, removedirs
and those from pathname manipulations, like path.basename, path.dirname, path.exist, path.isfile, path.isdir...